# Grails war dependency with other projects

Tags: grails, build

Running into issues where by I am forced to add custom jars in the grails/lib project.
We have two projects (web projects).
In the eclipse ide I do create project reference to take care of compile time dependency, but run into issue when I generate war...
as 'grails war' ends up recompiling all the groovy classes, its unable to find refrences of dependent jars/classes.

For now I have to bundle those jars as 3rd party jar in the lib directory, wondering if there is a better solution.
One thing to remember at run time both the project do exists in the same web container and interact with one another

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a better way. Use its built-in [dependency resolution](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dependencyResolution). You can add your dependencies to the `BuildConfig.groovy` instead of adding Jars to the `lib` folder. This is how you define a dependency

```
runtime 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
```

The Grails knows five different [dependencies scopes](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configurationsAndDependencies).

- build: Dependencies for the build system only
- compile: Dependencies for the compile step
- runtime: Dependencies needed at runtime but not for compilation (see above)
- test: Dependencies needed for testing but not at runtime (see above)
- provided: Dependencies needed at development time, but not during WAR deployment

Comment: Will this work if I reference some of the classes from jar file in the groovy classes ?

Comment: In order to reference you need to choose the scope `compile`

Comment: but with 'compile' won't it needs dependent jars in the lib ?

Comment: Can you name the dependent JARs files? Common JARs such as JAR of open source projects are stored in Maven repositories such as Maven Central or Bintrays JCenter. If you add these dependencies to your BuildConfig Grails will contact these repositories and download the JARs for you. So, no you do not have to add anything to your `lib` folder.

Comment: If you look at my problem statement, I have two web projects and 'grails' project references some of the classes from other web module. From the ide perspective I added those projects in my classpath/build path. but problem comes when I am generating war file using grails command, when it looks for dependency in 'lib'